# Arcpy get count feature layer and data count in SDE?

Tags: python, arcpy

If I am use Arcpy how can I get count feature layer and data count in SDE database connection.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include as much information as you can about what you are trying to do, and what happens when you try it.  Include a snippet of your code that shows your attempt, and the output of that attempt (including any error messages).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to Count features in a feature class / layer then use [Get Count](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/get-count.htm):

> Returns the total number of rows for a table.

From the help section of the tool:

```
# Name: fcCount.py
# Purpose: calculate the number of features in a featureclass

# Import system modules
import arcpy

lyrfile = r"C:\data\streets.lyr"
result = arcpy.GetCount_management(lyrfile)
count = int(result.getOutput(0))
print count
```

If you want to Count the feature classes instead, then:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.workspace = r"Database Connections\test.sde"
print len(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses())
```